# slice the video in the android by start position to end position

Tags: java, android

hi i have a video file of 30 minutes,but I want to slice video from `00:09:23` to `00:25:33`.
I want to extract some portion of video when user is playing that video via my application. While playing a video user can give start and end duration to cut the video. so are there any way to cut the video based on duration and save to sd card ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write some C glue code using the JNI conventions to expose the FFmpeg functionalities to Java code. Here's an example of a JNI method implemented in C from the Android NDK samples:

```
jstring
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz )
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !");
}
```

You also need some Java code to load the library and declare the native method.

```
public class HelloJni
{
    public native String  stringFromJNI();

     static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
    }
}
```

I found [this project on sourceforge](http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/) which already has implemented some JNI interface to ffmpeg to integrate it with the Java Media Framework. You may find it useful.

There's another Java FFI technology called JNA (Java Native Access) that allows you to declare native function prototypes in Java and call them directly. Using it may require less boilerplate code. See [this project](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/JNAOnAndroid) for an Android implementation. (I have never used it myself)

You will need to include [JNI](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/) wrapper methods that you can call from Java, that will in turn invoke the FFmpeg functions.

Answer (score -1):

There is not a way to do this via the included android api's.  You will need to write your own logic to handle this.  Most of the video editing applications use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20compile%20FFmpeg%20for%20Android) to handle this, you will need to write some C code and use the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) to accomplish this.  If you search google and stack overflow you will find many questions and resources to get started on this.  If you are unfamiliar with the NDK and/or ffmpeg it can seem overwhelming but once you get started you should be able to accomplish what you are looking for.